# UIAlertViews, UIActionSheets and keyWindow problems

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uialertview, uiwindow

I created an [iOS 7 passcode replica](https://github.com/rolandleth/LTHPasscodeViewController) and I have this problem I can't seem to solve. I need the lock screen view to be on top of everything else, so the app is covered in iOS' multitasking view, so I add it directly to the `keyWindow`. Everything fine so far.

The problem arises if there's an `alertView` or `actionSheet` (will only mention `alertView`s in this post, to keep it simple) open when I have to display the lock screen. It has been answered several times that there are no references to `alertView`s in iOS 7, which is true, and the window in which they are displayed is `_UIModalItemHostingWindow`, which has 2 `UIView`s, indeed with no reference to the `alertView`.

This `_UIModalItemHostingWindow` **also becomes the new `keyWindow`**, so it's on top of everything else, but it can not be found in `[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows` meaning if I add the lock screen to my former `keyWindow` (the default `keyWindow`, if you will), it will be beneath the `alertView` and its dimmed background, so the user can't interact with the lock screen before dismissing the `alertView`. The other option is detailed a bit further below.

The lock screen works like this: on `applicationDidEnterBackground` it checks if the passcode is enabled; if it is enabled and the passcode duration is 0 (user selected to lock the app immediately), it adds the lock screen now, so it covers the app in the multitasking view. Now, the option I mentioned above is to add the `alertView` to this `_UIModalItemHostingWindow` window, but when returning to the app, the lock screen view is displayed with a 1+ second delay (even though I added it before I went to background!) and the app isn't covered by anything in the multitasking view. (Currently it's displayed in the wrong position too, if you go ahead and download it, that is fixed, but I didn't pushed the commit yet).

I tried hiding and `removeFromSuperview` this `_UIModalItemHostingWindow`, but when coming back to the app, the `alertView` animation still runs as if it was just fired. I suspect the delay mentioned above also happens due to how Apple handles `alertViews` when coming back to foreground.

I also tried creating a new window and to make that the new `keyWindow`, but same thing happens.

Here's a small discussion about this, covering all the stuff I tried, maybe I missed something in this post.
https://github.com/rolandleth/LTHPasscodeViewController/issues/16

Any ideas? Except creating manual references to every `alertView` and `actionSheet` inside my app, because I'm trying to find a fix for the passcode library, not my own apps; I can find dirty workarounds for that, no problem :)

Update: The window is `_UIAlertOverlayWindow` if an `actionSheet` is used instead of an `alertView`, but it behaves the same as far as I can tell.

Comment: for the case of UIActionSheet, its window _UIAlertOverlayWindow is available in [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows, so you can resolve the problem with actionsheet. Me too not getting, how to resolve the case of alertview

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to have a lockscreen window instead of a lockscreen view.

Create a new `UIWindow`, set its frame to `UIScreen` bounds, put a simple `rootViewController` there that should handle rotation and display your "lock screen" views and set the `windowLevel` to `UIWindowLevelAlert + 1`.

Then set window's `hidden` to `YES`. Whenewer you want to show the lockscreen, just set `hidden` to `NO`.

I guess that adding a view to `keyWindow` also doesn't work when a popover/action sheet is displayed and also when a keyboard is displayed (keyboard has its own window on top of the key window).

Comment: I already tried creating a new UIWindow and set its level to 1997 (`UIWindowLevelAlert + 1`), and the value is indeed 1997, but still the window with the `alertView` appears on top. It just runs the firing animation all over again when coming back to foreground. Adding the view to `keyWindow` creates the problem I described, not being added before going to background, not being shown on the multitasking view and being shown after coming from foreground with quite a huge delay, after the `alertView` animation plays.

Comment: Hmm, I was clearly doing something wrong before, as now I tried creating a new UIWindow again and it appears over the `actionSheet`. Hmm, not that it matters anymore, but I wonder what I did wrong previously. Going to come back with final results, as I have to leave for now.

Comment: Well, this is funny. This approach works, but it has this problem: if no `actionSheet` or `alertView` is shown when going to background, it properly works when coming back (including the keyboard showing up). If one of them is present when going to background, when coming back the window is displayed properly over everything, but the keyboard doesn't show. No other difference but the existence of the `alertView`/`actionSheet`.

Comment: @Roland Are you making it the key window?

Comment: I was going to jump in and say yes I am, and I was, but apparently I was doing it in the wrong place. I moved the `makeKeyAndVisible` and now the keyboard properly shows. But it doesn't want to go away until the `actionSheet`/`alertView` is dismissed. The moment that gets dismissed, the keyboard gets resigned as well. I am calling `resignKeyWindow` (on the lock window) and `resignFirstResponder` (on the testField). So, when the passcode is correctly entered, the window gets hidden, the keyboard stays visible, the AV/AS window appears and I have to dismiss that, so the keyboard resigns too.